# xls file opens blank with R

Tags: r, xls

I have some *.xls files that are generated weekly from a system developed by my organization (the system is based on SYBASE).

The problem I have with these files is that when I try to open them with R, they generate a blank dataframe. This is fixed by opening the xls file and saving it without making any other changes.

I would like to know if anyone else has had this problem? The solution of opening and saving each file is not useful for me, since the number of files is large.

I have used the `read_xls` function from the `readxl` package.

This is my `sessionInfo()`

- R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
- Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
- Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)

Comment: I've seen things like this before. It's as if the systems are not exporting with all the encodings that are needed. So opening and closing the file in Excel fixes that. I got around this once by using a VBA script to loop through, open, and save all of the files, and then read into R. Not ideal at all, but it got the job done.

Comment: Yes, a VBA script is my first solution. But I wanted to exhaust the solutions directly with R. Because for an internal control I must save the date and time when the file is downloaded, and in that case I should first save the dates of the original files in R, then run the VBA script, and then run the rest of the code in R